# Return the int result of sql query to php echo?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

A little help would be lifesaving. I have an sql query that works in phpMyAdmin and gives me the result i need.
When i build this query into a php statement i cant seem to access the result (an integer)
I literally need to echo the value, so i need to output for exanmple " your number is" result.

here is my query:

```
$sqlstatement = "SELECT (SELECT `embark` FROM info ORDER BY `index_no` DESC LIMIT 1)-(SELECT `embark` FROM info ORDER BY `index_no` ASC LIMIT 1)";
$sql_result = mysqli_query($connection, $sqlstatement) or die (" Couldn't execute the SQL calculate disembark statement********");
```

If anyone can help i would really appreciate it
Scott

Comment: so show the code where you actually use `$sql_result`...

Comment: In what way is this code failing?

Comment: David - The sql works. i just need to pass the result to my php so i can present it to the user.

Comment: @JohnDowe Any PHP+MySQL tutorial should show how to do this. You call `mysqli_fetch_assoc` to retrieve the result row into an array, and then access `$row['embark']` to get the value of the column.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the row of results into an array, and then access the element of the array to echo it.

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_result);
if ($row) {
    echo "Your number is " . $row[0];
}
```

I used `mysqli_fetch_array` because you didn't assign an alias to the result column.

BTW, you can simplify your query to:

```
SELECT MAX(index_no)-MIN(index_no) FROM info
```

Comment: Thank you. I did not manage to get this working as i wished, and my dealine has passed, but thank you anyway.